# ERROR: Unable to cast COM object of type 'MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass' to interface type 'MSScriptControl.IScriptControl'

Tags: visual-studio, iis, com, vb6

I'm working on a old vb application and when I'm using this one, I got this folowing error:

```
document.all["ScoringMessageBox$MessageLabel"].innerHTML = "An error occurred while loading the score model.<br>SUCCESS: Set Model Language<br>FAILED: Set Model parameters<br>ERROR: Unable to cast COM object of type 'MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass' to interface type 'MSScriptControl.IScriptControl'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{0E59F1D3-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}' failed due to the following error: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).";
    var RedirectAfterClick = document.getElementById('RedirectAfterClick');
```

Here is a list of things I've already tried (google search) but without success:

- IIS Reset (web site hosted with IIS)
- Register Framework 1.4 && 2.0
- Download sct10en.exe and installation http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download
  /details.aspx?id=1949 (COM Component)
- Reinstallation of IIS
- Register the COM component manually

Please, could you help me with that ?

Comment: My company is using c# application and old vb application for the oldest client who don't want to upgrade their software (high cost).

Comment: Sure, it gets to be expensive to support customers that don't want to upgrade.  Don't forget to charge forward, they never will as long as you make it cheap for them to not do so.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue. The Script Control is only a 32-bit component. You can't have IIS running as 64-bit if you plan on using the Script Control.

Comment: Thank you for your response, sorry (my fault) the client (not me) is using Windows Server 2003 32 bits... I've checked with him the iis settings via web ex, and I don't have notified problem.

Comment: It should work fine then. You could try a simple .VBS that just does a CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl") and see it this works.

Comment: Indeed, i strongly believe this is the only solution. Thank you